# reset ddl in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

ive got a ddl in a gridview with two values: 0 = no and 1 = yes. I've also got an event on the dll SelectedIndexChanged so when the user selects 1 then it shows a panel with a form in it. the form has two buttons: submit and cancel.

what i'd like to do is when the user selects cancel reset the ddl in the gridview back to 0.

I have an event on the cancel button and can hide the panel with the form but I'm not sure how to find the ddl that triggered the event to show the panel. do i need to use the row datakey such as the id?

Comment: When the ddl is selected to yes, you could set the value of a hidden input field to the ID of the ddl that triggered it.  Then the cancel button would know by looking at the hidden value.

Comment: okay so I got the value of the row id and put it into a hidden field. now that i have that how to i located that row's ddl in the gridview and reset the ddl value to 0?

Comment: You will need to use javascript or jquery to set the ddl value back to 0.  I just read your comment, i said put the ID of the drop down list in the hidden field, not the row id.

Comment: oh - how do i get the id of the ddl?

Answer (score 0):

When your `SelectedIndexChanged` event occurs, note down the row index - in which the `DropDownList` is present - for example saving the row index in a hidden field. Then when the cancel Button is clicked, use that hidden field, extract the row index, find the `DropDownList` in `GridView` in that row and reset it.

Hint: Use `Control.Parent` to find the host of a control, for example `CType(mydropdown1.Parent, GridViewRow).RowIndex`

However doing all this through JavaScript would be much better, in this way your user would NOT experience the server round trips on each click, but obviously requires good grip on JavaScript.

Comment: yah - how the hey would i do that in javascript?

Comment: I would suggest that, you should first go with the way you are currently doing (i.e. without JavaScript). After you successfully done this thing then try with JavaScript, and if you face any problem, again post the specific problem in some other question

Comment: i got the row index and kind of know what you're talking about with your hint but not too sure.

Comment: got it with     Protected Sub btnEPCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEPCancel.Click
    Dim rowIndex As String = hfRowID.Value
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(gvLineItems.Rows(rowIndex), GridViewRow)
    Dim ddl As DropDownList = DirectCast(row.FindControl("ddlPed"), DropDownList)
    ddl.SelectedValue = "0"
    pnlEPed.Visible = False
    End Sub